# Generation and storage of all DES keys

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm writing Data Encryption Standard "cracker" using C++ and CUDA. It was going to be simple brute-force - trying all possible keys to decrypt encrypted data and check if result is equal to initial plain-text message.

The problem is that generation of 2^56 keys takes time (and memory). My first approach was to generate keys recursively and save them to file.

Do you have any suggestions how to improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don' really need recursion, neither you need storing your keys.

All space of DES keys (if we don't count 12 or so weak keys, which won't change anything for your purposes) is a space of 56-bit-long numbers (which BTW fit into standard uint64_t), and you can just iterate through numbers from 0 to 2^56-1, feeding the next number as a 56-bit number to your CUDA core whenever the core reports that it is done with the previous key.

If not for cores, the code could look such as:

```
for(uint64_t i=0;i<0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL /* double-check number of F's so the number is 2^56-1 */;++i) { 

  uint8_t key[7];
  //below is endianness-agnostic conversion
  key[0] = (uint8_t)i;
  key[1] = (uint8_t)(i>>8);
  key[2] = (uint8_t)(i>>16);
  key[3] = (uint8_t)(i>>24);
  key[4] = (uint8_t)(i>>32);
  key[5] = (uint8_t)(i>>40);
  key[6] = (uint8_t)(i>>48);
  bool found = try_your_des_code(key,data_to_decrypt);
  if(found) printf("Eureka!\n");
}
```

To allow restarting your program in case if anything goes wrong, you need to store (in persistent storage, such as file) only this number i (with cores, strictly speaking - the number i should be written to persistent storage only after all the numbers before it has already been processed by CUDA cores, but generally the difference of 2000 or so keys won't make any difference performance-wise).